# Converting a long-running synchronous function into async in Javascript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I'm using node to generate large RSA keys, the problem is that my function is synchronous and thus make the current thread stuck for a while.. so I was wondering how could I wrap it in some async operation (preferable a promise)

Here is my code:

```
const NodeRSA = require('node-rsa');
const key = new NodeRSA({ b: 4096 }); //make this async
```

Thanks!

Comment: You better consider moving the workload to a free thread by [using workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers). You can obtain your results through asynchronous messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this consumes a lot of time and you are okay with using HTML5, you can use a [Web Worker](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webworkers.asp). A web worker runs in the background is completely isolated from the main JS. This might be suitable for your task

There is a npm module containing an implementation of web workers for node.js; [npm workerjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/workerjs)

Comment: The OP appears to be running a node.js server

Comment: There is an implementation of web workers for node. I have added that to my answer.